# Use dynamic programming to merge two arrays such that the number of repetitions of the same element is minimised

Tags: algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

Let's say we have two arrays `m` and `n` containing the characters from the set `a, b, c , d, e`. Assume each character in the set has a cost associated with it, consider the costs to be `a=1, b=3, c=4, d=5, e=7`.

for example

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a']
n = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
```

Suppose we would like to merge `m` and `n` to form a larger array `s`.

An example of `s` array could be

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
```

or

```
s = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e']
```

If there are two or more identical characters adjacent to eachother a penalty is applied which is equal to: `number of adjacent characters of the same type * the cost for that character`. Consider the second example for `s` above which contains a sub-array `['d', 'd', 'd']`. In this case a penalty of `3*5` will be applied because the cost associated with `d` is `5` and the number of repetitions of `d` is `3`.

Design a dynamic programming algorithm which minimises the cost associated with `s`.

Does anyone have any resources, papers, or algorithms they could share to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: How is your 2nd example a merge? The order of the two arrays isn't preserved. Looks more like you are trying to find (one of the) best character sequences using the characters from the two arrays.

Comment: A merge would be if you have two piles of cards with letters on it and you build a new pile by taking a card from the top of one of the other piles and put it on the new pile until there are no more cards left to put on the new pile. Or not? (Ok compared to the initial piles the new pile would be in reverse order, but I think you know what I mean).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770052/minimum-repetitions-in-merged-array-of-characters