# Minimum repetitions in merged array of characters

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, computer-science

Suppose I have two arrays and I want to merge them so that the merged array has the **minimum amount of repetitions**. For example `[ 'x', 'x' ]` is a repetition.

```
arr1 = [ 'x', 'd', 'd', 'm', 'f', 'm' ]
arr2 = [ 'd', 'd', 'x', 'f', 'f', 'm' ]
```

**The only condition is that in the merged array, the elements from `arr1` and `arr2` must appear in their respective orders within `arr1` and `arr2`.** Below is an example of the merged array with 0 repetitions while maintaining this condition.

```
merged = [ 'd', 'x', 'd', 'x', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm' ]
```

I'm trying to relate this problem to popular dynamic programming problems to help me out. Are there any similar problems out there that I should look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I define the following function: **F(d, i, j) = the minimum number of repetitions possible from a string made of a prefix of `arr1` of length i and prefix of `arr2` of length j, followed by a ith (d=0) or jth (d=1) symbol from `arr[d]`**. Thus F(d, i, j) corresponds to a string of length i+j+1.

If you are familiar with the way Levenshtein distance is calculated, think of it as instead of assigning scores to the vertices of the grid we assign scores to the edges, where `d` signifies whether it's the horizontal or the vertical edge. This gives us a one-symbol 'memory', so we can detect repetitions.

The following C++ code calculates the minimum number of repetitions and prints a corresponding string in quadratic time:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits.h>

char A[32], B[32], C[64];
int score[2][32][32];

void print_result(int d, int i, int j)
{
    char c = d ? B[j] : A[i];
    int s0 = i > 0 ? score[0][i-1][j] + (A[i-1] == c) : INT_MAX;
    int s1 = j > 0 ? score[1][i][j-1] + (B[j-1] == c) : INT_MAX;

    if(s0 <= s1 && i > 0)
        print_result(0, i-1, j);
    else if(j > 0)
        print_result(1, i, j-1);

    printf("%c", c);
}

void print_result(int i, int j)
{
    if(score[0][i-1][j] < score[1][i][j-1])
        print_result(0, i-1, j);
    else
        print_result(1, i, j-1);
}

int main()
{
    fgets(A, sizeof(A), stdin);
    fgets(B, sizeof(B), stdin);

    int m = strlen(A) - 1; // -1 to remove LF
    int n = strlen(B) - 1;

    for(int j = 0; j <= n; ++j)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= m; ++i)
        {
            score[0][i][j] = !i && !j ? 0 : std::min(
                i > 0 ? score[0][i-1][j] + (A[i-1] == A[i]) : INT_MAX,
                j > 0 ? score[1][i][j-1] + (B[j-1] == A[i]) : INT_MAX
            );
            score[1][i][j] = !i && !j ? 0 : std::min(
                i > 0 ? score[0][i-1][j] + (A[i-1] == B[j]) : INT_MAX,
                j > 0 ? score[1][i][j-1] + (B[j-1] == B[j]) : INT_MAX
            );
        }
    }

    printf("repetitions: %d\n", std::min(score[0][m-1][n], score[1][m][n-1]));

    print_result(m, n);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response - its great! I translated your C++ code into Python to try and understand it a little better since I'm not familiar with C++. Are you able to help me explain why `std::min(score[0][m-1][n], score[1][m][n-1]))` is the number of repetitions and not `std::min(score[0][m][n], score[1][m][n]))`?

Comment: Also would you mind helping me understand your comment `// -1 to remove LF`, not really sure what it means :(

Comment: @user8888: The definition of my F(d,i,j) function wasn't aligned with the code. Apologizes for that! It's just a different parametrization of the grid and I fixed the definition. So to get the answer for a string of length m+n, there's no single number in the `score` array for that -- because it holds the scores an the edges but we need the score at the vertex (m,n). So we need to calculate the score of the final solution by an additional `min` of the incoming two edges (0,m-1,n) and (1,m,n-1).

Comment: @user8888: `// -1 to remove LF` removes the newline character retained by `fgets` as we want to ignore it. You don't need that part in python.